# Java recursively print array in reverse

Tags: java, arrays, string, recursion

The array is an array of strings. The array is `{"hello", "how", "are", "you", "?"}`

It sort of works, but the output mixes up the last 2 elements, and when I run my program the output comes out as `you ? are how hello`, it should be `? you are how hello`.

I put in a print statement to see what my left and right are and if they switch, but that didn't help since they only printed out the start values and nothing else.

Why is it printing out wrong? Is it not doing the recursion?

This is my method. It has to be done with divide and conquer.

```java
public void outrev() {
    outrev(0, a.length - 1);
}

private void outrev(int left, int right) {
    System.out.println("left a[" + left + "] is " + a[left]);
    System.out.println("right a[" + right + "] is " + a[right]);
    int mid;
    if (left > right) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else if (left == right) {
        System.out.print(a[left]);
    }
    else {
        mid = (left + right) / 2;
        outm(mid + 1, right);
        System.out.print(a[mid] + " ");
        outm(left, mid - 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, where is the recursion?

And, what is the definition of `outm`?

Comment: the recusion are the two outm( )'s, right? and what do you mean by whats the definiton of outm?

Comment: By definition, I mean, what is the function/method definition of `outm`? Shouldn't it be `outrev`?

Comment: As @ Sandeep said where is the Recursion buddy.what is outm()

Comment: @alexthefourth if the `outm` is replaced with `outrev`, then I think the piece of code is correct. Please **remark** the first two println statements when getting the output. Else the program would give correct output.

Comment: thats true, i noticed that the outm was wrong

Answer (score 1):

```
public void outrev()
{ 
    List<String> arr = Arrays.asList(a);
    outrev(arr);
} 

private void outrev(List<String> arr)
{

    System.out.println(arr.get(arr.size() - 1));
    if(arr.size() != 1){
        outrev(arr.subList(0, arr.size() - 1));
    }
}
```

You have to import

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

Dunno if that breaks your homework's rules. Notice out outrev calls itself, but stops calling itself once the list is one item in length? That is the primary tenant of recursion, i.e. a function that calls itself, and has a terminating condition. In your original code outrev isn't really calling itself; you are overloading outrev in one case however, but that is different than recursion -- unless outm, which you didn't define was intended to be a call to outrev.

You should also have this program check to make sure that the list isn't empty, as your teacher could throw that at you, and the code would fail in that case.

Remember, with recursion, it's best to think about in terms of:
1) What to do when I have zero items.
2) What to do when I have one item.
3) How to handle every other case where my list has more than one item.

Comment: @Bringer128, sometimes the best way to learn is by example. Thanks a lot for -1.

Comment: I am not trying to be malicious, and am happy to remove the downvote if you change your answer so that he can't just copy-paste it into his assignment/classwork. Have a look at [the tag wiki for the homework tag](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/homework/info).

Comment: I understand, but I think we simply have a philosophical difference here. The OP is making an effort to solve the problem, but having a lot of trouble. I feel like demonstrating to him how to solve the problem is the best way to teach. Even if he copies the answer verbatim, it's his responsibility to understand things when the material shows up on an exam. Check metastack; there's quite a bit of discussion about HW questions, contrary to that wiki page you showed me. If you really want to use your rep to drag me down for trying to being legitimately helpful though, that's your prerogative

Comment: Fair enough. Unfortunately I can't remove the downvote unless the answer is edited (StackOverflow won't let me).